# Encrypt password in front with Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, password-encryption

i need to encrypt password into the front of my Vue JS web app, i already have a hash encrypter on API, but in the signin or signup call the password is perfectly legible, how can i do?
I use Vue JS in the front and Nove JS for the API

Comment: Encryption on the client should only ever done through https,anything else is security theater

Comment: Where are you encrypting? In the web app, that is, in the client, or on the server? Usually you transmit the plain text password over the internet via a POST request and have the server hash the password. This allows you to add salt and pepper to it, because any hashing method on the client can be reverse engineered. Security for the plain text password must be provided by the TLS connection (HTTPS).

Comment: I make an HTTP call as POST with the readable password, and then the server encrypts it and puts it in the database, but I wanted (in addition to the server encryption) the client to send the encrypted password (possibly different from how it is put in the DB). This is just for more security

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved:
I found this:

```
npm install crypto-js
```

CryptoJS is a very simple tool, I use this for my web app

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js")

methods: {

  encrypt (src) {
    const passphrase = '123456'
    return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(src, passphrase).toString()
  },

  decrypt (src) {
    const passphrase = '123456'
    const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(src, passphrase)
    const originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
    return originalText
  }
}
```

I've learn all here: [labnol.org](https://www.labnol.org/code/encrypt-decrypt-javascript-200307)
This is npm CryptoJS: [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)